# Audio and Lock-Screen Hotkeys broken

Tags: 12.04, sound, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

Some days ago (probably after some package updates) some of my hotkeys stopped working. It is no longer possible to change the volume via the Volume up / Volume down hotkeys on my keyboard and neither is to lock the screen via STRG+ALT+L, it simply happens nothing.

When I am in the keyboard-settings of my Ubuntu and click the option for Volume down and then pressing the hotkey the hotkey is properly detected.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem myself an after many hours of head scratching i found a solution that work for me:

The problem for me was in dconf so i installed `dconf-tools`

in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then launch `dconf-editor`

navigate to `org->gnome->setting-daemon->plugins->media-keys`
and change the value `active` to true (put the tick like in this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naN0v.png))

now the buttons should work as usual (at least worked for me :) )